# Getting exc_bad_access in UITableViewController while getting object from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a subclass of UITableViewController, and I init the subclass with a NSMutableArray of another custom class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NUBCheckpointModel.h"

@interface NUBUserCheckpointModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString* objId;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString* userId;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString* checkpointId;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSDate* dateAdded;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NUBCheckpointModel* checkpoint;

+ (NUBUserCheckpointModel*) fromJson: (NSString*)json;

@end
```

This array that is generated from another ViewController, gets passed into this subclassed TableViewController, of which contain this property

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* userCheckpointData;
```

This property is set like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame withType: (TableType)typeOfTable fromParent: (UIViewController*)parent data: (NSMutableArray*)ucpData
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.parentController = parent;
        self.userCheckpointData = ucpData;
        [self styleTable];
        [self addPullToRefreshHeader];
        typeCategory = typeOfTable;

    }
    return self;
}
```

All is fine up to this part, and any manipulation including trying to get an object from the array works fine. I tested it.

The code I used to test the array is:

```
NUBUserCheckpointModel* model = [self.userCheckpointData objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(model.objId);
```

However, this very same code, when used here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Gives me exc_bad_access. May I know why this happens? I can't seem to figure out why. I'm using ARC btw. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding the property, you need to take care of the memory management. For string, it is not good practice to set assign property.

Instead , do as following,

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* objId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* userId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* checkpointId;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDate* dateAdded;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NUBCheckpointModel* checkpoint;
```